# Lightning model shouldn't come in case of error

Tags: lightning

I have a custom button in which I am calling a lighning component. There is an if condition in which I am trying to show an error by using the `$A.get("e.force:showToast");` event. [image]

How can I make this model disappear so that we dont have to cancel it manually in case there is an error showing up.
This is an extension to this question here - [Link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/270292/calling-docusign-vf-url-from-lightning-component/270301?noredirect=1#comment408530_270301)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [force:closeQuickAction](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:closeQuickAction):

```
$A.get('e.force:closeQuickAction').fire();
```

This will close the current modal dialog.

Comment: thank you @sfdcfox